# How can i find the five longest words in stringr::words

Tags: r

I have a sample named new that are sampled from words I have to find the 5 longest words of this sample.I'm not allowed to use grep.

Comment: You can use `nchar` or `str_count` i.e. `tail(words[order(nchar(words))], 5)`

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `nchar` and `order`

```
tail(words[order(nchar(words))], 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `nchar`

```
> s[order(-nchar(s))][1:5]
[1] "dfasdoinvde" "doasdinx"    "dfaosdne"    "abfddf"     
[5] "dfab"
```

**Data**

```
s <- c("abfddf","dfab","doasdinx","dfaosdne","dfasdoinvde","ddf","xuev")
```